# Easier way to execute the last echo command in a shell?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm using bash shell.  If I want to execute the last echo command, I can run

```
history | grep echo
```

and then grab the last echo command from what is displayed and run it.  I was wondering, is there a shorter way to do this?  I'm happy to use another shell if that allows me to somehow more easily execute the last "echo" command if all I know is the command started with "echo."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

type to command line this: `!echo`

Answer (score 5):

Using reverse [interactive search](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Searching):

- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
- start typing for the command you want
- when the shell has found the one you want, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want to use a *previous* echo command

- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
- type `echo`
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> again, repeatedly until you find the command you want.
- if you go too far back in history, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> searches in the opposite direction.

If you don't want to execute the command, but edit it a bit, when you find the command you want:

- don't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- instead, hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> or left or right arrow key

If you want to reject the command,

- clear the command-line <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> (the latter leaves the line behind, though).